# how to get Bytes of a file for sending in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, fileopenpicker

I'm a newbie in UWP and i want to open a file of any type and transmit the bytes of it to the reciever. forexample for a jpg file i wrote this code:

```
// Create FileOpenPicker instance    
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

// Set SuggestedStartLocation    
fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =         PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

// Set ViewMode    
fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

// Open FileOpenPicker    
StorageFile file = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
byte[] bytesRead = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);

 string  Paths = 
 @"C:\\Users\zahraesm\Pictures\sample_reconstructed.jpg";
 File.WriteAllBytes(Paths, bytesRead);
```

the two last lines are for writing the bytes into a file supposing in the receiver. However i keep getting the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.'

Comment: please clarify which exact line are you getting thisexception on ?

Comment: i get the error on line : File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code.

```
try {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker {
                ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary,
                FileTypeFilter = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" }
            };

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null) {
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)) {
                    var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));

                    var LoadReader = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);

                    byte[] pixels = new byte[fileStream.Size];
                    reader.ReadBytes(pixels);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

consider wrapping last operation in **Task.Run()**

```
await Task.Run(()=>{
    byte[] bytesRead = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);        
    string  Paths = 
    @"C:\\Users\zahraesm\Pictures\sample_reconstructed.jpg";
    File.WriteAllBytes(Paths, bytesRead); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should directly read the bytes from the StorageFile returned from your FilePicker, lest you end up with File permission errors in the future.

```
StorageFile file = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
byte[] bytes = System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(buffer);
```

You should also use `await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(targetFile, myBytes)` to write.

Unless you have `broadFileSystemAccess` in your package Manifest, you should generally avoid using the `System.IO` API unless you know your application explicitly has permission to access files in that area (i.e., your application's local storage), and instead use `Windows.Storage` API's

Check MSDN for [File Access Permissions for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for more information on file permissions.

And if you do use `System.IO`, always perform the work on the background thread via `await Task.Run(() => { ... }`